# Access forbidden! While running Laravell Project

Tags: php

I am facing below error while running laravell project first time on my local xamp server

**Access forbidden!**
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

> Error 403: localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.4

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing todo with Laravel, its the folder permissions, you need to make the root folder readable and make sure .htaccess is readable. As its local I would suggest setting the root folder to readable by everyone and try again.

Also it could be because you are not pointing your server to the public folder of your Laravel application

Comment: thanks, how make .htaccess readable, furthermore i have already other custom php projects which is run perfectly on the same server.

Comment: As other projects are working fine. Are you sure you have set the document root of the server to the public directory of your laravel project? e.g.  `/my/laravel-project-folder/public`

Comment: sorry, i do not have idea how to set this directory, kindly let me know how to do

Comment: i do not have exeriance with xamp however try this link to help you: https://www.codementor.io/magarrent/how-to-install-laravel-5-xampp-windows-du107u9ji#xampp-virtual-host